# Hold data from EventListener in MutableLiveData

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to retrive data from firestore and want to keep it in shared view model. Basically I have a main activity and 2 fragments that need to retrieve data from shared view model of main activity. My current method is :

```
class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {

private val firebaseUtils = FirebaseUtils()

fun getTempWords(localeLearn: String): LiveData<DocumentSnapshot> {
    val document = firebaseUtils.getTempWordsLocaleRef(localeLearn)

    return FirebaseDocumentLiveData(document)
}}
```

What i want is that just retrive data once and keep it in MutableLiveData and pass to fragmetns.

Edit:
What I'm done is:

```
var tempWords : MutableLiveData<DocumentSnapshot> = MutableLiveData()
fun getTemp(localeLearn: String): LiveData<DocumentSnapshot> {

    if (tempWords.value == null) {
        val document = firebaseUtils.getTempWordsLocaleRef(localeLearn)
        tempWords = FirebaseDocumentLiveData(document)
    }
    return tempWords
}
```

But if i kill the fragment and recreate it again, it calls EventListener in FirebaseDocumentLiveData(document) class again.

Edit 2:
My Fragment

```
private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //
    model = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
}

//
 model.getTemp(mLocaleLearn!!).observe(this, Observer {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the question? it looks like you successfully made it.
You ask how you can access the data from your fragments?

in view model class

```
private final MutableLiveData<Item> data = new MutableLiveData<Item>();
```

in your fragments:

```
model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
```

Comment: do you create the SharedViewModel as i wrote?

Comment: add viewModel initialization in activity and in fragments please

Comment: yeah i do create the SharedViewModel as you wrote. In FirebaseDocumentLiveData class there are OnActive and OnInactive methods. Somehow those methods are connected with fragments instead activity.

Comment: as i see in your fragment 2 you call ViewModelProviders.of(this).... , replace this to getActivity() or for kotlin use activity!! , if you use this in fragment it will create new instance of viewModel and the data.value is null.

Comment: Actually "this" refferes activity also i tried using "activity!!" but result is same.